# Why does this `do-while/for loop` never end if you give an invalid input?

Tags: java, for-loop, filereader, do-while

I have a `for` loop nested inside a `do-while` loop which is to read through a text file and look for the  given input. I have noticed that it works perfectly fine if you give an input which exists in the file, however can someone help me understand why the program never exits the loop if you give an input which does not exist in the text file, even though it should exit when the variable with the text from the file becomes `null`. I have  posted all relevant code from the method where the for loop is being executed, including the part where it gains the user input; just to be clear, there are no errors given when `compiling` or running the program.

```
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("VirtualATM.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        System.out.print("Enter your pin: ");
        char [] EnterPin = {0, 0, 0 ,0};
        try{
            EnterPin = System.console().readPassword();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());          
        }
        boolean pinTrue = false;
        String LineFromFile = null;
        LineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String [] PinSearch = LineFromFile.split("\\s+");
        String UserPin = java.util.Arrays.toString(EnterPin);
        String PinMod = UserPin.replaceAll("\\[", "");
        String PinMod2 = PinMod.replaceAll("\\,", "");
        String PinMod3 = PinMod2.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String PinToWrite = PinMod3.replaceAll("\\]", "");
        do{
            for(int search = 0; search < PinSearch.length; search++){
                String SearchForPin = PinSearch[search];
                if(SearchForPin.matches(PinToWrite)){
                    pinTrue = true;
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                }
                else if(search => PinSearch.length){
                    System.out.println("Error! Invalid pin.");
                }
            }
            LineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }while(pinTrue == false && line != null);

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Was => meant to be >=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the line processing to be inside the loop, after each line you read. Otherwise, you only process the first line you read before the loop.

```
    do{
        for(int search = 0; search < PinSearch.length; search++){
            String SearchForPin = PinSearch[search];
            if(SearchForPin.matches(PinToWrite)){
                pinTrue = true;
                System.out.println("Success!");
            }
            else if(search => PinSearch.length){
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid pin.");
            }
        }
        LineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (LineFromFile != null) {
            PinSearch = LineFromFile.split("\\s+");
            UserPin = java.util.Arrays.toString(EnterPin);
            PinMod = UserPin.replaceAll("\\[", "");
            PinMod2 = PinMod.replaceAll("\\,", "");
            PinMod3 = PinMod2.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            PinToWrite = PinMod3.replaceAll("\\]", "");
        }
    } while(pinTrue == false && LineFromFile != null);
```

Comment: Adding `PinSearch = LineFromFile.split("\\s+");` in the loop gives me a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Because you're testing `line`, but reading into `LineFromFile`.

Change this

```
}while(pinTrue == false && line != null);
```

to something like

```
}while(!pinTrue && LineFromFile != null);
```

And, as [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26122782/2970947), your line processing logic should be in the body of the `do`, so

```
do{ 
  String LineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
  String [] PinSearch = LineFromFile.split("\\s+");
  String UserPin = java.util.Arrays.toString(EnterPin);
  String PinMod = UserPin.replaceAll("\\[", "");
  String PinMod2 = PinMod.replaceAll("\\,", "");
  String PinMod3 = PinMod2.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
  String PinToWrite = PinMod3.replaceAll("\\]", "");
```

Comment: That's not the only problem.

Comment: It's defined before the loop (I didn't mean to remove any code outside the loop). I guess you can move that logic to be at the start of the loop instead of having it in two places.